# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsondata); force datetime to string column

Tags: c#, json, json.net

this is my json :

```
[
 {"ID":"1","DATETIME":"2018-05-02T00:00:00"},
 {"ID":"2","DATETIME":"2018-05-02T00:00:00"},
 {"ID":"3","DATETIME":""},
 {"ID":"4","DATETIME":"2018-05-02T00:00:00"}
]
```

I'm using `DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsondata);` to convert from json to datatable, however with the null datetime column I get the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <> in
>   DATETIMEColumn.  Expected type is DateTime.

So how can I convert my json to datatable with all columns is string

Comment: Why not define a class and deserialize as an IEnumerable of that?

Comment: @GPW my json have dynamic columns

Comment: @jimboR There is nothing dynamic based on your example

Comment: @DavidG: Depending on the condition that my json string may have some other attributes,but ID and DATETIME are always there.

Comment: @jimboR You could define the class as having nullable fields for the optional data and it should work fine - those fields will just be null if they're not in the JSON...  that's what I would do.  Accepted answer below is good for your specific question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the `Serializer` settings to Ignore `DateTime` parsing so that the dynamic JOSN can be converted into `DataTable`. **Downnside** of that that `DateTime` will be read as strings in `DataTable`.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
        };
        
string json = "[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"DATETIME\":\"2018-05-02T00:00:00\"}, {\"ID\":\"1\",\"DATETIME\":\"\"}]";

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json, settings);
        
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.Rows.Count);
```

You can read `DateParseHandling` setting at [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm).

**Check** this [Live Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9WJRRC)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of serialising to a `DataTable` is that you get on control of how the columns are created, and in your example the empty date is the problem. While it is possible to create your own custom `JsonConverter`, that would be quote complex and lots of code, my advice would be instead to deserialise to `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. For example:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsondata);
```

Now you can loop through your dynamic data:

```
foreach (var dictionary in result)
{
    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
    }
}
```

Which would give you output like this: (including any additional properties are in your JSON data:

```
Key: ID, Value: 1
Key: DATETIME, Value: 2018-05-02T00:00:00
Key: ID, Value: 2
Key: DATETIME, Value: 2018-05-02T00:00:00
Key: ID, Value: 3
Key: DATETIME, Value: 
Key: ID, Value: 4
Key: DATETIME, Value: 2018-05-02T00:00:00
```